# What happened to the old Theatre SE proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

Someone just made an SE proposal for "Theatre," which is a great idea, but I'm absolutely sure that we used to have one. I contributed some questions, including one about "finding tickets for West End shows"... but now I can't find it. What happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proposals that lack activity are automatically deleted after some time.

This proposal did not have any activity since September 20th.

The proposal was automatically deleted.

Comment: I didn't know that. I'll have to make sure the new one doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Correct. There was a "Theater" proposal that was deleted due to inactivity (nothing since September 20th).

Comment: @robert we should update the /faq to indicate the policy on deleting inactive stuff

Comment: @Robert: what is the inactivity threshold?

Comment: @Charles Stewart: A proposal may be deleted after 30 days of inactivity.