# How can I find out what happened to my Area 51 proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

I made an Area 51 site proposal a few days ago. Today I logged into Area 51. I don't see any trace of the proposal in my profile, through search or anywhere. I'm guessing the proposal might have been deleted. In any case, how can I find out what happened to the proposal?

Comment: In terms of "how", can you verify if the proposal appears under your own profile? http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/156437/fiksdal

Comment: @RobertCartaino It doesn't. That's the first thing I checked.

Comment: I will attempt to get that addressed in the next round of Area 51 updates.

Comment: @RobertCartaino You want to implement that one should be able to view one's own proposals, even after they're deleted? That sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually when you can't find your proposal it means it got deleted, as the [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284451/152859) already says.

To be sure, you can [try Google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=site:area51.stackexchange.com+%22scandinavian%22), it will usually have a cached copy of the proposal.

To find out why it got deleted, you can ask in [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), which is the equivalent of its meta site.

Example for such a question: [What happened to 'content creators' proposal?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22148/what-happened-to-content-creators-proposal) which is most likely what happened in your case as well: no five example questions, or 5 followers, in three days.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the [Scandinavian Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102659/scandinavian-languages) proposal—yes, it has been deleted. You can ask one of the 10k+ [users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users) for more details—they are able to view deleted proposals.

Comment: You mean 6 users, out of which only one is active.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What do you mean? OP didn't mention any number?

Comment: @Fiksdal I mean take a look in the list of users you linked to. Count how many have 10k+ reputation. Check their profiles. Only one was active in the last couple of days, the rest weren't around for weeks, months, and years. (so "asking one of them" is not really relevant.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard But they are active on other SE sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But OP didn't say anything about how many there were?

Comment: @Fiksdal my point is, there are very few users with 10k rep. Chances one of them will be willing to take a look are not so high, especially when they're not active on Area 51, meaning they probably won't really care what's going on there. Plus, asking them about every deleted proposal (there are many) will most likely get them... not so happy.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh, I see. Yeah. It's quite impractical, really. I wish proposals could just be closed rather than deleted, and that users could see the closure reason. I saw a feature request about that and upvoted it.

Comment: Fiksdal, would you mind posting a link to that feature request? Thanks!

Comment: @Sue [Close, rather than delete inactive Area 51 proposals](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71630/310998)