# Where can I ask questions about a Broadway show?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about the broadway play Hello Dolly. I recently watched it with my family and was confused about one of the plot points.

Stack Exchange has sites for movies, games, SciFi, anime, literature, and music, but I haven't found a site for theater.

Is there a place to ask questions about a broadway show?

Comment: There was a theater proposal a long time ago, but it was [deleted for inactivity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69971/323179). :P

Comment: I would suggest Literature, but if it`s about writing a theater then the Writing stack exchange would be a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

[Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) would be my guess.

As long as the question is about the *plot* of the musical or play.

They accept questions about plays, and musicals are plays with music. Even the lyrics of music are on topic on Literature, so the lyrics of a musical would be, too.

From their [help page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> We don't have a specific answer--we're still trying to work this out--but questions have been successfully asked about written stories, comic books, plays, and poetry.

If you have further questions about the *music* of a musical, try the [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 2):

Try asking it on Literature. We do have questions about plays, and we also have questions about music. The caveat here is that it's possible that your question might get closed. If it's about the words or the lyrics, it's definitely on-topic. If it's about the music or the melody, it *might* be on-topic; we're still in the process of determining the boundary line for those questions. If it's about the actors or the facial expressions or the set... I don't know! Try asking it and seeing what happens.

> I want to ask a question about the broadway play Hello Dolly. I recently watched it with my family and was confused about one of the plot points.

Then it probably should be on-topic, but I can't guarantee anything. We're still figuring out a lot of scope stuff.

Comment: Odd. The answer from the Literature mod gets a downvote and the answer from a non-mod gets an upvote ... and they say the same thing.

Comment: @Catija Wording maybe? "_...would be my **guess**_" This is Q&A not Q&G, maybe someone didn't like you guessing.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Only this answer (by a deleted user) got a DV (and Catija was never a mod on Literature.SE as far as I know), so Catija was surprised that her answer was upvoted and this one downvoted.

Comment: @AnneDaunted ah right, I can't quite wrap my head round all that but I'm happy not quite getting what's going on. :) There was a mystery, I offered a possible answer, if it isn't right no worries. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking for the same thing. :( Bummer.

I've got a specific question about the musical similarity of two songs in two separate Andrew Lloyd Webber musicals. I doubt Literature is the right place for it. I'm going to try https://music.stackexchange.com and see what happens.