# Where can I ask questions about plays and musicals?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As there is no Theatre SE, I wonder where I should post questions about plays and musicals?

I couldn't decide between Movies & TV or Music or even Literature.

More specifically, in this case it would have been a question about the musical "Phantom of the Opera". Which is also a movie, a book, etc.

The question, in specific, would be about the production and why the phantom only wears a mask on half of his face.

Comment: It depends on the question, without an example it is hard to say. Music is only for learning and theory, literature would take plot or lore based questions and TV and Movies is more pop culture and enthusiast based. This is very related but not sure if it is a dupe without more information https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300800/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-a-broadway-show

Comment: @MarkKirby I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "plot or lore based questions", but I suspect Literature's scope is wider than you think :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm to too familiar with the site, I was thinking more, if the OP had a question about the plot or the world of Phantom it would go there but you might be right, I may of underestimated the scope based on my own definition narrow of literature (books).

Comment: @MarkKirby Echoing my previous commenter's sentiments I think you're equally underrepresenting Movies & TV's scope when reducing it to "pop culture". ;-)

Comment: We have [Music: Practice and theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/), [Music and Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/), [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

[Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) welcomes questions about plays and musicals. We don't subscribe to an ultra-strict interpretation of literature, but pretty much anything which involves words (e.g. not just instrumental music) for literary or entertainment value (e.g. not recipe books or instruction manuals) is likely to be on-topic. There's even [already a tag](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-phantom-of-the-opera-musical) for the musical *The Phantom of the Opera*.

From the [help centre](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> We interpet ‘literature’ in a broad sense, including written, spoken and sung works, in all genres, languages and forms: poetry, plays, stories, novels, lyrics, comic books, essays, belles-lettres, and so on.

I don't know anything about the scope of Music Stack Exchange, but at Movies & TV Stack Exchange I suspect that [the tag for *The Phantom of the Opera*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-phantom-of-the-opera) is only for *film* adaptations and not for the musical except potentially as it relates to the film.